# Where EntityFramework is putting my data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I just started a new project with ASP.NET MVC5 and Entity Framework 6. My problem is, that I cannot find where EF is putting my data.

For testing I added rows to the database using EF `context.Users.Add(...); context.SaveChanges();` and I was successful, but I cannot see the database created (just before doing an screenshot i have refreshed the database list).

[image]

When I run `update-database` in Package Manager Console, database creates as it should, but on the web, it uses something else (same database where my 9 entities are saved).

Could someone tell me what is happening, where EF is saving those entities and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Silly question, but did you refresh the view on the SQL Server Object Explorer tab?

Comment: EntityFramework uses the database configured from your web.config file, under connectionstrings. There's no error here as I can tell. What do you mean with "how to fix it"? Fix what exactly? And also, are you saying that your 9 entities show up when you publish to another website, or that it *doesn't* contain your 9 entities?

Comment: @Patrick I have configured connnection string in the web.config, and it is correctly being used as you can see from the image. "How to fix it" - how to make EF to use the same database as he created during update-database command. Now EF is using correct connection string but it doesn't use the database that it targets as you can see from the list of databases, there is no WarehouseManager database... After not seeing the database I tried to save some data using EF, and from the result (those 9 entities) I can say that it works, but i have no idea where is it saving them.

Comment: Did you try connecting via other means (like SQL Server Management Studio or something)? This looks rather weird indeed... so just to discard it being a problem of Visual Studio Explorer not showing the updated databases. I know it *shouldn't* but this should be an easy test and would discard the obvious stuff

Comment: Can you use the "Server Explorer" instead? Then you have your connectionstrings (DefaultConnection for instance) under Data Connections that you can double click. The SQL Server Object Explorer seems to share connectionstrings between projects, so you are probably connected to a whole different database in the image you've attached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your probably using a Local db, which defaults to

`C:\Users\user-name\`

The following explains this functionality

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/10/28/localdb-where-is-my-database.aspx

Comment: Thanks, yes I'm using LocalDB and connection string is visible in the image, but when I connect to it ((LocalDB)\v11.0) through "SQL Server Object Explorer" I cannot see my database "WarehouseManger". It looks like it ignores my connection string and uses something else...

Comment: Thanks. I was able to find an mdf file the inside directory suggested and indeed, it was using this as it's database. After all, I ended up using SQLEXPRESS, instead of localDB.

Comment: Pleasure @BenasRadzevicius happy coding